# update same record which fires a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to update the same record which fires a trigger. I have done that using "BEFORE INSERT"
option. But note that I have use a transaction to rollback the operation if there is an any faliure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GANUKA.INTF_CONTROLLER_UPLOADER
BEFORE insert ON GANUKA.INTF_CONTROLLER for each row
DECLARE 
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    max_id INTEGER;
    stat VARCHAR2(32);
begin

select :new.id into max_id from dual;
select :new.status into stat from dual;



 IF STAT = 'NEW' THEN   --ONLY NEW UPLOADS WILL CONTINUE FOR PROCESS
    :NEW.STATUS := 'STARTED';
     max_id := GANUKA.BACKOFFICE_UPDATE(max_id); --PL/SQL function
    :NEW.STATUS := 'COMPLETED';

ELSE
   :NEW.STATUS := 'ABORTED';
    :NEW.REMARKS :='STATUS IS NOT RECONGNIZED';

END IF;

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
       ROLLBACK;
        RAISE;

end;
/
```

Problem is if there is an an any exception I want to update the record to set the state as 'Failed'. Can any one tell me how to do that.

Comment: Why isn't the `GANUKA.BACKOFFICE_UPDATE()` function setting the status to `STARTED`, and then either `COMPLETED` or `FAILED` as appropriate? This could then be an `AFTER INSERT` trigger to just call the function for `NEW` records. (As it is, the `STARTED` status is never seen anywhere anyway). You may have locking issues updating the same record, I suppose.

Comment: As I know we cant use 'AFTER INSERT' option and update the same record by using 'NEW' keyword. That's the problem I have. Is there a way to use "AFTER INSERT" and update the same record?

Comment: I just don't think a trigger is the right way to do this.  Why not just write a PL/SQL process?

Comment: I agree with Tony.  Attempting to do this in a trigger makes no sense.

Comment: I want to do this process when an entry is inserted in to the table. As I know that event can catch only using a trigger. Can I do that with PL/SQL ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why do you use autonomous transaction here and why do you have to commit/rollback in the trigger...

Comment: within the PL/SQL function there are several data transactions between tables. So I need to make sure that data transfer has occur without any problem. If there is any failure I need to roll back whole process. But need to keep the record which fires the trigger and update it status as 'FAILED'

Comment: Then perform the `INSERT` first, call the PL/SQL function. If there is a failue then rollback, followed by another `INSERT` marked as FAILED. Triggers are semi-evil, Autonomous Transactions are semi-evil. Combining them is full-evil!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GANUKA.INTF_CONTROLLER_UPLOADER
BEFORE insert ON GANUKA.INTF_CONTROLLER for each row
DECLARE 
    max_id INTEGER;
    stat VARCHAR2(32);
begin

 max_id := :new.id;
 stat := :new.status;

 IF STAT = 'NEW' THEN   --ONLY NEW UPLOADS WILL CONTINUE FOR PROCESS
    DECLARE 
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN
      max_id := GANUKA.BACKOFFICE_UPDATE(max_id); --PL/SQL function
      COMMIT;
      :NEW.STATUS := 'COMPLETED';
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        :new.status := 'FAILED';
    END;

 ELSE
    :NEW.STATUS := 'ABORTED';
    :NEW.REMARKS :='STATUS IS NOT RECONGNIZED';

 END IF;

end;
/
```